# Can we interchange the limit here?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the limit $ \ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int e^{-|x|+\frac{1}{n}} \cos \left( x-\frac{1}{n} \right) d \lambda (x)$ by interchanging limit and integral.

Can we interchange the limit here?

**Answer:**

I think this is based on the concept of term-term by integration and uniform convergent.

Since the integrand $ f_n(x)=e^{-|x|+\frac{1}{n}} \cos \left( x-\frac{1}{n} \right) $ is uniformly convergent and each $f_n(x)$ is integrable, we can pass or interchange the limit under integration sign.

Therefore,

$ \ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int e^{-|x|+\frac{1}{n}} \cos \left( x-\frac{1}{n} \right) d \lambda (x) \\ =\int \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-|x|+\frac{1}{n}} \cos \left( x-\frac{1}{n} \right) d \lambda (x) \\ =\int e^{-|x|} \cos (x) d \lambda(x) $

=limit.

But I am not clear is the function $f_n(x)=e^{-|x|+\frac{1}{n}} \cos \left( x-\frac{1}{n} \right)$ really uniformly convergent or not .

Comment: Do you know Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem?

Answer (score 1):

To interchange limit and integral you don't need assumption about uniform convergence.

There is a powerful theorem called : [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)
 which says that if there is an integrable function $g$ such that :

$$\forall n, \forall x \in [a,b], f_n(x) \leq g(x)$$

Then we can interchange limit and integral.

In your example we have :

$$f_n(x) = e^{-\mid x \mid + \frac{1}{n}}\cos \left ( x-\frac{1}{n} \right) $$

Let's suppose we are working on : $\mathbb{R}$, then we have :

$$f_n(x) \leq e$$
Hence by the dominated convergence theorem we have :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \mathrm{d}x$$